# A question on eversion of (odd) spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds

At  the right  column of the  page  654  of  the  paper, 
[R. Palais, The Visualization of Mathematics: Towards a mathematical Exploratorium, Notice  AMS](http://www.ams.org/notices/199906/fea-palais.pdf) it  is  written "There can be no   eversion of a circle (or  any   odd dimensional spheres)".

In that paper the  eversion is  defined  as a  regular homotopy  between identity  and the  antipodal map.

I  wonder  what is  my  mistake  to think that $f_t(z)=e^{it}z, \quad t\in [0, \pi]$ is  a  regular homotopy  between the  identity and the  antipodal map on the  circle?

Comment: I think there is a problem of terminology. In even dimension, an eversion is a regular homotopy between the identity and the antipodal map. But in odd dimension, an eversion should be a homotopy between the identity and $(x_1, \dots, x_{2n}) \mapsto (-x_1, \dots, -x_{2n-1}, x_{2n})$. Otherwise the antipodal map is just a rotation and it doesn't turn the circle "inside out".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  in this  case  what would  be  the  signification of  the  word "Eversion" for  the  map you mentioned (In odd dimension)

Comment: As I said, for an odd sphere $S^{2n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, I believe the (inexistent) eversion should be a regular homotopy between the identity embedding $f : S^{2n-1} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}, x \mapsto x$ and the other embedding $g : S^{2n-1} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}, (x_1, \dots, x_{2n}) \mapsto (-x_1, \dots, -x_{2n-1}, x_{2n})$. The antipodal map doesn't turn an odd sphere inside out.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  Yes  but  why this  called "Eversion".  I  mean that, litteraly speaking, it is more reasonable that (a homotopy  between the  identity  and )the  antipodal map would  be  called "eversion"(In both odd  and  even case).Am  I  right?

Comment: An eversion is when you turn the sphere inside out. Try to draw pictures, a rotation of $S^1$ does not turn it inside out.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  Yes I  see thank you.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  But  what  about even dimension? In your  first  comment you wrote  it is  the  antipodal  map.  But if it is  the  case, the  problem is  obvious(The  degree is  an  obstruction)  while  in the paper, the  even  case is  discussed  technically.  What is  the true  definition of "Eversion"?

Comment: A regular homotopy doesn't need to preserve the degree, actually. Indeed, there do exist eversions of even-dimensional spheres.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  May  be  I  am  mistaken, but the degree, being  apparently  an  smooth concept,  has a topological interpretation and is  homotopy invariant.Right?

Comment: It's homotopy invariant for maps $S^2 \to S^2$, but a regular homotopy is about the embedding $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. There will be self-intersections during the eversion.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  In that paper he  talk about the  Gauss  map  but it  is  not  writen  clearly what is the role  of  Gauss  map in this situation?

Comment: It provides a different kind of invariant, called the "turning number". It is an invariant of regular homotopies. The turning number of $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is $1$ while it is $-1$ for the (almost) antipodal, so they cannot be regularly homotopic. But for even spheres, the turning number is the same (and indeed, there exists an eversion).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  So it seems that it is  merely   a  kind of typos in the  paper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me summarize the comments. An "eversion" of $S^n$ is a regular homotopy between, on the one part the "identity" embedding $S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and on the other part an embedding $S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that turns the sphere inside out.

For an even sphere, the antipodal map turns the sphere inside out (AKA reverses orientation), thus we speak of an eversion for a regular homotopy between the identity and the antipodal map. But for an odd sphere, the antipodal map preserves orientation, so we must use something else. For example, the map $S^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$ given by $(x_1,\dots,x_{2n+2} \mapsto (-x_1,\dots,-x_{2n+1},x_{2n+2})$. I suspect that this is essentially a typo in Palais's paper. People aren't used of talking about eversion of odd spheres, because, well, they don't exist...

Let me also point out that an eversion is not a homotopy of self-maps $S^n \to S^n$. So notions such as the degree of a map are *not* preserved. It is not a contradiction that there exists an eversion for even spheres, even though the degree of the identity is $1$ and of the antipodal map $-1$.

However, there exists a different invariant, called the "turning number". This invariant is basically the degree of the self-map of $S^n$ induced by the differential of an embedding $f : S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (where we used the fact that a regular homotopy is an immersion at each moment, to get a self map of $S^n$: the Gauss map). The turning number of the identity is $1$. The turning number of the "not antipodal" map $S^{2n+1} \to S^{2n+1}$ is $-1$, so there can be no eversion of an odd sphere. However, the turning number of the antipodal map of $S^{2n}$ is $1$, so there is no contradiction.

The legends say – but it was before my birth, so others may confirm/infirm/clarify – that Smale's advisor's, Bott, thought that Smale's proof of the existence of an eversion of the $2$-sphere<sup>(1)</sup> was wrong; without even looking at the proof, just based on general expectations. Apparently Bott either because he believed an eversion preserved the degree, or (more likely?) because he thought the turning number of the antipodal was $-1$. As we now know, Smale's result was correct: there exists an eversion for $S^2$. It was actually a shock at the time, I gather. It was especially frustrating since the proof was not constructive, and people had to wait years for an explicit eversion.

(1) and of $S^6$, and the proof of inexistence of an eversion for other even spheres – thanks to Mike Miller for this clarification!

Comment: Smale's result is stronger: the only spheres $S^n$ that admit eversions in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ are the tautological $n = 0$, the famous $n = 2$, and the less-known $n=6$, tied to when spheres are parallelizable.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks, I didn't know that actually!

Comment: I am sorry if my question is elementary. According to the argument in the paper, using Gauss normal map,  we conclude that a regular homotopy gives us a self map homotopy. So in the case of $S^2$, existence of an eversion implies that the identity and the amtipodal maps are homotopic self map. What is my mistake?

Comment: Let $f,g : S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. A regular homotopy between $f$ and $g$ induces a homotopy between the two Gauss maps $G_f, G_g : S^n \to S^n$. But the Gauss map of the antipodal is not the antipodal. If $f : S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is the antipodal, then the degree of the Gauss map is $(-1)^n$. So there is no contradiction...